# actionscript 3.0 OPP type and class

Tags: actionscript-3

What's the different between
var myObject : Sprite = new Sprite();
and
var myObject : Sprite = new MovieClip();

Comment: thank you all for your help.

I'm using the composition pattern. All of the components are sprite except for one which is a movieClip. When updating all of the components, how would you handle the exception of movieClip?

Comment: @quan, I would recommend you post that as a separate question, and describe in more depth what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MovieClips and Sprite are separate classes, albeit related to each other because MovieClip extends Sprite. As such, MovieClip has all the same capabilities that Sprite has, and it also adds more, mostly related to timeline animation (play(), stop(), gotoAndPlay(), addFrameScript() et c.)

Because MovieClip has all the same capabilities as Sprite, you can assign a MovieClip object to a variable typed as Sprite.

```
var myObject : Sprite = new MovieClip();
```

Sprite, however, does not share all of MovieClip's functionalities, so this does not work the other way around:

```
// Will not work
var myObject : MovieClip = new Sprite();
```

If you want to know the inheritance chain for a particular class, check out the documentation, e.g. [for MovieClip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/MovieClip.html): . You can see that it extends Sprite, which in turn extends InteractiveObject, and so on.

In language-agnostic terms, this is called inheritance, one of the strengths of which is [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

Answer (score 0):

One of them isn't right, and one of them is :)

```
var myObject:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

is fine, you're saying it's type Sprite (the bit after myObject:), and then calling the Sprite constructor after the '=': new Sprite();

In the other you're still saying it's type Sprite (myObject:Sprite), then calling the constructor of MovieClip when you say new MovieClip();

If you want to create a MovieClip:

```
var newMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
```

Comment: Both are "right", but one relies on the concept of inheritance, while the other does not.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that

```
var myObject : Sprite = new Sprite();
```

declares a new variable of type `Sprite` and assigns it with a new `Sprite` object, while

```
var myObject : Sprite = new MovieClip();
```

declares a new variable of type `Sprite` and assigns it with a new `MovieClip` object.

`MovieClip` inherits from `Sprite`, so there is no problem with casting a MovieClip to Sprite.
There are some differences between MovieClip and Sprite. The major difference is that a MovieClip has a timeline and the Sprite doesn't.